# Is there a way to add current date to a received JSON in php?

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have an andriod app sending data in JSON to a php script and appending it to a mysql table, is there any way to insert the current date without adding it to the app.  I am trying to get php to add the current date to BoughtDate inside the same query.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors',1);

include('../htconfig/dbConfig.php'); 
$dbSuccess = false;
        $dbConnected = mysql_connect($db['hostname'],$db['username'],$db['password']);

        if ($dbConnected) {     
            $dbSelected = mysql_select_db($db['database'],$dbConnected);
            if ($dbSelected) {
                $dbSuccess = true;
            }   
        }


$data_back = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));


$userName = $data_back->{"User"};
$password = $data_back->{"Pword"};
$BoughtFrom = $data_back->{"Bfrom"};
$VIN = $data_back->{"VIN"};
$Color = $data_back->{"Color"};
$MakeIndex = $data_back->{"Make"};
$ModelIndex= $data_back->{"Model"};
$Year = $data_back->{"Year"};
$Bid = $data_back->{"Bid"};
$INV = $data_back->{"PurchasePrice"};
$BidContact = $data_back->{"Contact"};
$BidEmail= $data_back->{"Email"};


mysql_query("Insert Into tblinventory (VIN, MakeIndex, ModelIndex, Year, Color, Bid, INV, 
BidContact, BidEmail, BoughtFrom, BoughtDate)
VALUES ('$VIN','$MakeIndex', '$ModelIndex', '$Year', '$Color', '$Bid', 
'$INV', '$BidContact', '$BidEmail', '$BoughtFrom', '$BoughtDate'") or die (mysql_error());



$responses = array();
 {
    $responses[] = array( $VIN . " " . $MakeIndex . " " . $ModelIndex." ". $Year." " );
}


header("Content-type: application/json");


echo json_encode($responses);
?>
```

Comment: Replace `'$BoughtDate'` with `NOW()`?  (NOTE: `NOW()` is a MySQL function)

Comment: Tried that, didn't work, also tried $BoughtDate = NOW(); as a value before and inside the $date_back

Comment: @Glenn I agree with rocket, use `NOW()` directly in you sql

Comment: Is the data type of BoughtDate a DATE, TIMESTAMP or DATETIME?

Comment: DATETIME, I ended up changing it to a timestamp and defaulted it to the current time and date

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As first the var $BoughtDate is not existent in your current code.

You can fill $BoughtDate by using php function `time` wich returns the current unix timestamp.

See http://php.net/time for further explanation.

Code Snipped:

```
$BoughtDate=time();
```

Comment: I tried this but it still throw an error, putting $BoughtDate=time(); inside the $data_back and before it. Works just fine when it's removed.  I am working in a MYSQL 5.0 database if this is a factor.

Comment: Please adjust your question by adding your new code and the error. We cant help without precision questioning.

Answer (score 1):

Let mysql do that for you using CURDATE.  See t[his article](http://www.gizmola.com/blog/archives/51-Exploring-Mysql-CURDATE-and-NOW.-The-same-but-different..html) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things, that *needs* your attention.

First the `$data_back->{"bar"}`, is a unnecessary syntax. Instead use `$data_back->bar`. (usefull comments below answer on this subject) Also the " is for string parsing, you can replace it with a ' as long as it is only a string without variables.

Secondly the `mysql_connect`, `mysql_select_db` and `mysql_query` functions are *deprecated* (check the php manual and the big warning box in each of these function).

The query is vulnerable to SQL injection (serious security issue). 
Instead use mysqli or pdo and prepared statements. You can find tons of resources on this subject on google.

See @gview answer for info on inserting the date in the column,  make sure the column type matches.

Comment: its not a strange syntax, actually it is safer, because for example if you have a key `"foo bar"`, `$data_back->foo bar` will fail but `$data_back->{"foo bar"}` will work

Comment: @meda I must disagree, naming a objects public attributes with a space is bad (in any case). If there was a special case where op actually was forced to a key with spaces, I could understand it, but this is not the case, it is clearly a beginners mistake.

Comment: I get your point it is not as readable as your suggestion or even associative arrays (which is even cleaner). but I wouldn't say it is strange or a mistake.

Comment: Yes, beginner's mistakes all over the place, I am aware of the SQL injection, just trying to make it work at this point, will fix it when I have succeeded.

Comment: @meda I would say it is both a strange and a mistake (but ofc we are both entitled to our opinions). Object properties should not contain spaces.
Glenn, sure, it was not to point at things, just to make sure you knew.

Comment: @RonniSkansing as you said "should" but not "must". It is perfectly valid JSON to have a space in the key , not saying its recommended but its possible and when you don't have control over the json structure, the only way to parse would be using the "strange/mistake" syntax.

Comment: @meda you are completely right. It is perfectly valid JSON. But why use such a syntax when none of the keys use it? Anyways I can agree that strange/mistake was not the best wording. I have replaced it with "unnecessary". Thanks for the input =]

Comment: good adjustment you got my vote now :). well it is useful not only for space, it comes handy with numeric keys, or with dollar sign. its rare but its useful